# Get User Information using AD Identity Access in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have followed the link to create Azure AD Identity access authentication.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-dotnet-how-to-use-access-control/

I followed the above link and on the Claim page I retrieve the information below.

IsAuthenticated: True

http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier    *******************
http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider   uri:WindowsLiveID
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod    http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/authenticationmethod/password
http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant   *****

But I want to Microsoft logged in account information like name or email. unable to retrieve the information at my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {            
      ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
      string fullname = 
             string.Format("{0} {1}", cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value,
             cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value);
      ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Dear {0}, welcome to the Expense Note App", 
                        fullname);
      return View();
     }
```

Comment: I used this but getting error. Unable to access ClaimTypes.GivenName and ClaimTypes. When I listing the claim types it shows only. 

These claim types are listed after authentication
'
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier  

http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider  

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod  

http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant'

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Accounts (AKA LiveID) does not provide ACS with the user's personal info nor email, you only get an ID representing the user. Google IDs will get you user names and emails.

By design, can't be changed.

Comment: Add to this, you get more details about the account you would have to use the Live SDK http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/live/ff621310.aspx